# Drop down to choose search engine

Tags: javascript, html

What I wish to do is to tie the choosing of a search engine to a list. I pick the correct option, type what I'm searching for and press a button and it will open a new page to search on that homepage.

How would be the easiest way to solve this. Below are just some placeholders for the search engines.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="engine">
    <option value="fedex url">Fedex</option>
    <option value="dhl url">Dhl</option>
    <option value="google url">google</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<button type="submit">Search</button>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The process you are looking for is basically, read the dropdown and use it to set the url for the search page, append the search text to that url, and window.location.href to go to that page. (or use window.open for new window). You just have to look at each search engine results page to get the format of the url needed.

Comment: I'm currently trying to learn javascript do you have an example of what you are referring to? Thanks for the fast answer by the way.

Comment: no problem, give me a couple minutes... I will get one together.

Comment: I have solved it thanks to your help. You pointed me in the right direction for it. I will post the information below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select google and type a word.. then search...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        var url = document.getElementById('engine').options[document.getElementById('engine').selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.href = url + "?q=" + document.getElementById('searchtext').value;
    }
</script>

    <select id="engine" name="engine">
        <option value="fedex url">Fedex</option>
        <option value="dhl url">Dhl</option>
        <option value="https://www.google.com/search">google</option>
    </select>
    <input id="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" onclick="search();" value="Search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dr. Aaron Dishno for pointing me in the right direction. With his help i managed to puzzle this together.

```
<select name="engine" id="searchstring">
<option value="http://www.fedex.com/">Fedex</option>
<option value="http://www.dhl.com/">Dhl</option>
<option value="https://www.google.com/">Google</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<button type="submit" onclick="search()">Search</button>
```

And the Javascript code.

```
        function search() {
        var dropdown = $("#searchstring").val();
        window.open(dropdown, '_blank');
    }
```

A simple solution to a simple problem, thank you once again Dr. Aaron Dishno for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Now i'm just going to need to put the rest in, with the search box to append the the information, but that will be an easy task now that i know how to do it.